# Change the value of a field in a class depending on the result of a function

Tags: python, django

how can I modify the value of a boolean field of a class depending on the result of a function?

What I am trying to do is a function that ping (icmp) an ip that is in the 'Cliente' class and depending on the result, change the value 'ping_status' in the class.

I'm new to python, so I don't have a lot of knowledge, and I've been trying to do this for 1 week, but I can't.

models.py

```
class Cliente(models.Model):
razon_social = models.CharField('Razon Social', max_length=50)
numero_cuenta = models.CharField('Numero de cuenta',max_length=6)
nombre_contacto = models.CharField('Nombre del contacto', max_length=50)
numero_del_contacto = models.CharField('Numero del contacto', max_length=10)
email = models.EmailField('Correo Electronico', blank=True, null=True)
tiene_as_propio = models.BooleanField('Tiene ASN priopio', default=False)
ipv4 = models.GenericIPAddressField('IP', default='192.168.0.0')
segmento = models.CharField('Segmento', max_length=15)
asn= models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True, null=True)
created = models.DateTimeField('Creado el', auto_now_add=True ,blank=True, null=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField('Actualizado el', auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
topologia = models.FileField('Topologia', blank=True, null=True)
ping_status = models.BooleanField('Ping', blank=True, null=True)


def Meta(self):
    verbose_name = 'cliente'
    verbose_name_plural = 'clientes'

def __str__(self):
    return self.razon_social
```

My function looks like this:

```
def do_ping():
    """Realice un nuevo ping y guárdelo en la base de datos."""
    ip_clientes = Cliente.objects.values_list('ipv4')

    for ip in ip_clientes:
        ip = (list(ip))
        for ping in ip:
            ping = subprocess.call(['ping', '-n', '1', '-w', 
                                                  '2',ping],
                                              stdout=open(os.devnull, 'w'),
                                              stderr=open(os.devnull, 'w'))
```

But after this I don't know what to do to get the class value and modify it

Regards

Comment: So you want to save the value of `ping` to the ping field in the `Cliente` model?

Comment: Also why are you converting the IP to a list? The assumption is a `GenericIPAddressField` has one IP in it.

Comment: @onyeka: because the `.values_list(...)` wraps the values here in singleton tuples. But it 8is not a good idea to use `.values_list`s in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the *exit code* of the process to check if the given host could be reached. We can furthermore use [**`.bulk_update(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk_update) to update the `.ping_status` of the objects:

```
def do_ping():
    ip_clientes = list(Cliente.objects.all())
    for ip_client in ip_clientes:
        ping = subprocess.call(
            ['ping', '-n', '1', '-w', '2', str(ip_client.ipv4)],
            stdout=open(os.devnull, 'w'),
            stderr=open(os.devnull, 'w')
        )
        ip_client.ping_status = ping == 0
    Cliente.objects.bulk_update(ip_clientes, ['ping_status'])
```

Comment: This did exactly what I needed.

I just had to correct a few typing errors in 'ipv4' and add the correct value for the '-n' option